# Generate Array of months with moment - Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, momentjs

My goal is to generate an array of months from today date month to 1 year in the past. So it will look like this

(based on today date 04-05-2022)

```
const months = ['Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
```

My current try to generate my array :

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const months = []
        const dateStart = moment()
        const dateEnd = moment().subtract(11, 'month')
        while (dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'months') >= 0) {
            months.push(dateStart.format('MMM'))
            dateStart.add(1, 'month')
        }

        console.log(months)
        return months

   },[])
```

Normally i think it has to be ok , but in my output i get an empty Array . Does somebody know what am i doing wrong ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead off using `diff()`, why not use `isBefore()`

Also, you're adding 1 month to `dateStart` but that needs to be `dateEnd`

```js
const months = []
const dateStart = moment()
const dateEnd = moment().subtract(11, 'month')

while (dateEnd.isBefore(dateStart, 'day')) {
    months.push(dateEnd.format('MMM'))
    dateEnd.add(1, 'month')
}
months.push(dateEnd.format('MMM'))

console.log(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```json
[
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May"
]
```

Comment: Hmm okey . I see my mistake, but i need to have the current month also in my Array. Instead of 11 elements i need to have `May` as the twelfth and last element inside.

Comment: Since thats out of the loop, I'd just add one more month after the `while`. Changed it in my answer.

Comment: Indeed you are right. An month can be added separately. Thanks for the tip and the explanation !